# TinyMCE table column properties

Tags: tinymce

TinyMCE editor seems to lack the capability of applying table cell properties to the whole table column (which would be much less trivial problem, than applying to the whole row - that functionality is there).

Is there a working soultion for that (patch, plugin..)?